# Problematic subqueries in one query

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a SQL query and I am stuck.

Query result should contain below columns:

- ItemCode (which is unique item number)
- LatestReceiptDate (which is latest receipt date of ItemCode)
- LatestIssueDate (latest issue date of ItemCode)

I was trying to use subqueries in main query but in result I got the same date in every row of `LatestIssueDate` and `LatestReceiptdate`

Like this...

```
Select Distinct 
    I.ItemCode, 
    LatestReceiptDate = (Select top 1 (MH.MoveDate) 
                         from inItem as I 
                         left join InMoveLn as ML on I.ItemID = ML.ItemID 
                         inner join InMoveHd as MH on ML.InvMoveID = MH.InvMoveID 
                         where Mh.transactiontypeID like '5001' 
                         Order by Itemcode desc),
    LatestIssueDate = (Select  top 1 (MH.MoveDate) 
                       From inItem as I 
                       left join InMoveLn as ML on I.ItemID = ML.ItemID 
                       inner join InMoveHd as MH on ML.InvMoveID = MH.InvMoveID 
                       where Mh.transactiontypeID like 
        '5013' 
                          or Mh.transactiontypeID like '5003' 
                       Order  by ItemCode desc)
from 
    initemstore as S
left join 
    initem as I on I.ItemId = S.ItemID 
left join 
    inMoveLn as ML on ML.ItemID = S.ItemID 
inner join 
     inMoveHd as MH on ML.InvMoveID=MH.InvMoveID
order by 
     I.Itemcode
```

I spent couple hours and could not go any further. I will appreciate any help

This is what I get from using above query

```
ItemCode  LatestReceiptDate         LatestIssueDate
100001    2011-09-12 15:26:18.000   2015-04-14 09:49:07.627 
100002    2011-09-12 15:26:18.000   2015-04-14 09:49:07.627
100003    2011-09-12 15:26:18.000   2015-04-14 09:49:07.627
100004    2011-09-12 15:26:18.000   2015-04-14 09:49:07.627
100005    2011-09-12 15:26:18.000   2015-04-14 09:49:07.627
```

Comment: You don't have to use "top 1" to retrieve last date of EACH ItemCode. This way, you always retrieve the last date of all the table.
You must use "MAX(MH.MoveDate)", and a "GROUP BY ItemCode" clause to obtain last date of each group of ItemCode.

Comment: I tried MAX but receive error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The subquery returns all the rows with the same MAX value. Add DISTINCT clause to the subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is complex and contains joins with other tables with no field in the result set. Assuming it was right anyway you can write that as:

```
WITH  lrd ( ItemCode, LatestReceiptDate )
        AS (
             SELECT ItemCode, MAX(MH.MoveDate)
             FROM   inItem AS I
             LEFT JOIN InMoveLn AS ML ON I.ItemID = ML.ItemID
             INNER JOIN InMoveHd AS MH ON ML.InvMoveID = MH.InvMoveID
             WHERE  MH.transactiontypeID LIKE '5001'
             GROUP BY ItemCode
           ),
      lid ( ItemCode, LatestIssueDate )
        AS (
             SELECT ItemCode, MAX(MH.MoveDate)
             FROM   inItem AS I
             LEFT JOIN InMoveLn AS ML ON I.ItemID = ML.ItemID
             INNER JOIN InMoveHd AS MH ON ML.InvMoveID = MH.InvMoveID
             WHERE  MH.transactiontypeID LIKE '5013' OR
                    MH.transactiontypeID LIKE '5003'
             GROUP BY ItemCode
           )
  SELECT 
DISTINCT  I.ItemCode, lrd.LatestReceiptDate, lid.LatestIssueDate
  FROM    initemstore AS S
  LEFT JOIN initem AS I ON I.ItemId = S.ItemID
  LEFT JOIN inMoveLn AS ML ON ML.ItemID = S.ItemID
  INNER JOIN inMoveHd AS MH ON ML.InvMoveID = MH.InvMoveID
  INNER JOIN lrd ON I.ItemCode = lrd.ItemCode
  INNER JOIN lid ON I.ItemCode = lid.ItemCode
  ORDER BY I.Itemcode;
```

Comment: This works fine but it display all dates except null's. Can we fix it?

Comment: Yes you can. Your SQL is rather complex enough. Maybe you should use SqlFiddle and give some sample data along with what you want to achieve.

Comment: Cetin Basoz-I have managed to get null's - just changed Inner Joins  to Left Join's'. Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate that